# NetSuite Inventory detail subrecord should have bin(inventoryassignment) according to suitescript condition

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am new to scripting in NS so I have issue where i want to script on inventory detail subrecord on item receipt. So when I click on Inventory Detail on line level of item receipt so over there in the bin number right now all the bin numbers are visible but i need to filter out according to my script which I am unable to do it since it is not allowing me to edit the sub record.Based on my condition in the script it should show only that bin number.I am using user event script before load function..Can any one help me in this issue I am stuck in this

[image]
As seen in the image all the bin numbers are shown but i want to show specific bin number based on some condition via user event script before load function but i am not able to edit the subrecord

Answer (score 0):

I do not think manipulation of native NetSuite functionality is permitted in this instance.

Alternative to your filtering solution, why not use the BEFORE SUBMIT function of your current user event script to analyse the inventory detail of each line, and if it does not comply to the set condition(s), return FALSE, else return TRUE?